# How to debug Iphone alignment issues?

Tags: iphone, html, css, windows-7, simulator

My client web page is having a little text alignment issue on the iphone.

Can some one help me any find good emulators that I could install in my windows 7 computer to debug these type of issues?

I don't have an iphone.  How can I debug these smart phones issues?

Answer (score 0):

I know in firefox you can use ctrl+shift+m to change the resolution and simulate mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

Please check it at http://www.browserstack.com as it is the simulator that is closest to the real thing.

this is what i used

note: this is have time limitation if you exceed you need to sign up...... just a tips...